# Finding the inverse of this matrix.

Tags: matrices

I need to find $A^{-1}$ as a polynomial, given
$$
8A^{19}+15A^{17}-24A^{16}+9A^{15}-16I=0
$$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$.

Comment: I got that $a^-1= (79/8)I$ is that right? how do I write it as a polynom?

Comment: How did you manage to get that?

Comment: I accidently multiplied it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A^{-1}=\frac 1 {16} (8A^{18}+15A^{16}-24A^{15}+9A^{14})$.

Comment: That is the answer according to the book. How did you do it? ty :)

please upvote it guys don't downvote it

Comment: @GhnbTrcv $A^{-1}A^{19}=A^{18}$ etc.

Comment: To the downvoter: I typed this answer only after realizing that OP was unable to use my comment. Normally I would not post an answer to this type of question.

Comment: Thank you very much!! now I understand what you did there. the 16 came from right side.

Comment: please upvote he helped me a lot

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sir I understand and completely agree with you. A $+1$ from me.

Comment: @GhnbTrcv You too can can upvote and click the tick-mark(accept)  if it has helped you

Comment: @Ak19 "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Yes but you can click the accept (tick-mark).

Comment: Sorry, but this is (in my opinion) a bad answer. Just an expression, without any explanation. How does this help future readers of this thread?

Comment: @MartinR He did explain me before in comments but after I didn't get it he used the answer to explain me further

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Write $8A^{19}+15A^{17}-24A^{16}+9A^{15}=16I$ and factor $A$ on the LHS.

Comment: I got that $A^{−1}$=(79/8)I is that right? how do I write it as a polynom?